# How to get marker based on latlng in leaflet?

Tags: javascript, optimization, leaflet, markers

I want to find and remove marker based on it's coordinates. Or remove all the markers in the given geometry. There are few solutions I'm aware of. First is to store all the markers in a map or array, and the second is to remove whole level with markers and add another one (updated) - both of this solutions are not performance friendly if we talking about thousands of markers. And I didn't found a way to get a marker by it's coordinates natively.

I'd be glad if someone had any ideas about it. Thank you for the attention!

Comment: You can loop over all markers and check if the latlng is equal

Comment: Well, if there are hundreds of thousands of markers? Anyway, get the marker by coords is O(1) and loop over all markers is O(2n)

Comment: So use a hash table, feed the coordinates as the key, and get O(1) lookups. You'll still have the problem of what to do if there are two data points with the same exact coordinates.

Comment: I took care of it by uniting markers that have ~near the same location. Hash table is not bad solution, if there were no other options, I would proceed with this one, however, I was hoping there are more elegant solutions. I don't want to store hash table with half of million items without need.

Comment: From where do you know what latlng you want to remove? Maybe you can reference the marker in the html

Comment: @FalkeDesign, meh, coords are from database

Comment: "_I don't want to store hash table with half of million items without need_" but "_I want to find and remove marker based on it's coordinates_" sounds like more than enough need to me. There is no magic. Either index or scan.

Answer (score 0):

I've finished with a structure like this for adding and removing markers:

```
let markerSet = {}

const saveMarker = (coords, marker) => {
    const [ key1, key2 ] = coords
    markerSet = {
        ...markerSet,
        [key1]: {
            ...markerSet[key1],
            [key2]: marker
        }
    }
}

const removePointer = (coords) => {
    const [ key1, key2 ] = coords
    const marker = markerSet[key1][key2]

    if (!marker)
        return

    markers.removeLayer(marker)
    delete markerSet[key1][key2]
}
```

`coords` is latlng array